# How to clear Kivy Core image on button press so that the widget is empty?

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

**Requirement**

My sqlite3 Db contains Blob and Text data, on deleting the selected row of data from the db the txt & blob data is removed from the db. I'm trying to set the widget to None so that the CoreImage widget appears blank after the delete() is called. However, the residual image is still visible. How can I go about this?

The code snippet is as follows.

```
delete(self):
    try:
        conn.execute("DELETE FROM EMPDB WHERE EMPID=?", (no))
        conn.commit()
        # NAME OF THE IMAGE WIDGET = ATTEMPTING TO SET IT TO EMPTY/NONE
        self.one_image.source = " " OR "None"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Image *reload()* function

## Snippet

```
delete(self):
    try:
        conn.execute("DELETE FROM EMPDB WHERE EMPID=?", (no))
        conn.commit()
        # NAME OF THE IMAGE WIDGET = ATTEMPTING TO SET IT TO EMPTY/NONE
        self.one_image.source = " "
        self.one_image.reload()
```

[Image » reload()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.reload)

> ```
> reload()
> ```
>
> Reload image from disk. This facilitates re-loading of images from
>   disk in case the image content changes.

[Image » source](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.source)

> ```
> source
> ```
>
> Filename / source of your image.
>
> source is a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) and defaults to None.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation references and code snippet : )